# Trying to Concatenate various columns with Dates into a cell on a seperate column

Tags: google-sheets, formula

```
=CONCATENATE(TEXT('Concat Sheet Data'!T9:AD, "DD-MM-YYYY"))
```

Example:

```
2/feb/2020,3/feb/2021
```

I tried the above, but doesn't function.

Comment: all into a single cell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(TEXTJOIN(",", 1, IF('Concat Sheet Data'!T9:AD="",,
 TEXT('Concat Sheet Data'!T9:AD, "DD-MM-YYYY"))))
```

if you hit a concat limit use:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF('Concat Sheet Data'!T9:AD="",,
 TEXT('Concat Sheet Data'!T9:AD, "DD-MM-YYYY\,"))),,9^9)),,9^9))
```